# SVG hovers with fallbacks

Tags: svg, hover, png, fallback

What is the bestpractice, when I need to have SVG images with SVG hovers with fallbacks?

I mean SVG images with PNG fallbacks (normal, reaponsive 2x, 3x), and change them on hover to other SVG images with PNG fallbacks?

Is it better to use `<img />` or `<picture>` + `<source />` + `<img />` tag with jQuery *(or vanilla, but I already use jQuery)*, or to have it all in CSS as backgrounds? If jQuery, does it mean swapping srcsets? If CSS, how do I best include @2x and @3x image versions?

Also, how does the used method affect preloading of the hovers? It would surely be much better without blinking.

So far I have this, I need to change them on hover to 1hov.svg, 1hov.png, 1hov@2x.png, 1hov@3x.png

```
<a href="#">
 <picture>
  <source type="image/svg+xml" srcset="logos/1.svg">
  <img src="logos/1.png" srcset="logos/1@2x.png 2x, logos/1@3x.png 3x" alt="logo">
 </picture>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a HTML + jQuery solution I found. It swaps the src and sourcesets to their hover alternatives. Includes the hovers preloading.

**HTML**

```
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <picture>
                <source type="image/svg+xml" srcset="logos/1.svg" data-swap-srcset="logos/1hov.svg">
                <img src="logos/1.png"  data-swap-src="logos/1hov.png"
srcset="logos/1@2x.png 2x, logos/1@3x.png 3x" data-swap-srcset="logos/1hov@2x.png 2x, logos/1hov@3x.png 3x" alt="logo">
            </picture>
        </a>
```

**jQuery**

```
//preload hovers
$("source[data-swap-src]").each(function(){
    $('<img/>')[0].src = $(this).attr("data-swap-src");
});
$("img[data-swap-src]").each(function(){
    $('<img/>')[0].src = $(this).attr("data-swap-src");
    $('<img/>')[0].srcset = $(this).attr("data-swap-srcset");
});

$("a").hover(function(){
   var newone = $(this).find("img").attr("data-swap-src");
   $(this).find("img").attr("data-swap-src", $(this).find("img").attr("src"));
   $(this).find("img").attr("src", newone);
   newone = $(this).find("img").attr("data-swap-srcset");
   $(this).find("img").attr("data-swap-srcset", $(this).find("img").attr("srcset"));
   $(this).find("img").attr("srcset", newone);
   newone = $(this).find("source").attr("data-swap-srcset");
   $(this).find("source").attr("data-swap-srcset", $(this).find("source").attr("srcset"));
   $(this).find("source").attr("srcset", newone);
 }
);
```